# Generating PDF in next.js

Tags: pdf, next.js

Hii i am trying to generate PDF in next.js. I tried many libraries like react-pdf, jsPDF etc. but all they are client side library they need window to perform their action. Is There any solution for generating pdf in next.js. If Present then please suggest with code example.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/stanleyfok/nextjs-pdf

Comment: @ddon-90 There's also this blog post about that: https://medium.com/@stanleyfok/pdf-generation-with-react-componenets-using-next-js-at-server-side-ee9c2dea06a7

Answer (score 4):

i recommend to use the api routes of next.js and use a node.js pdf library. On the frontend you access the api with the correct path to return the pdf and just render it.

[next.js api routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)

[pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib)

Example:

```js
import { PDFDocument, StandardFonts, rgb } from 'pdf-lib'  
export default async (req, res) => {
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create();
    // do pdf stuff  
    const buffer = await pdfDoc.save();
    res.send(buffer);
};

export const config = {
    api: { bodyParser: false, },
};
```

Comment: Thanks tom but i got solution with this approach,its work fine for me. If something wrong in this approach please correct me 
```export const jsPDF = () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            let jsPDF = null;
            const module = await import("jspdf");
            jsPDF = module.default
            await import('jspdf-autotable');

            return resolve(jsPDF);
        }
        return reject("not working")
    })
}```

Comment: Hey, i do not know which lib you are using, on the pdf lib i linked it looks like this (code not tested)

```js 

import { PDFDocument, StandardFonts, rgb } from 'pdf-lib'

export default async (req, res) => {

const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create();

// do pdf stuff

const buffer = await pdfDoc.save();

  res.send(buffer);
};

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

```

Comment: i am using jsPdf lib

Comment: the thing is, i think this a a client library and is not supporting node.js.  And your Promise await.. ist very confusing.

Answer (score 3):

As you said that both `react-pdf` and `jsPDF` are client side libraries
but still you can use them in Next.js
By setting flag SSR to false and use dynamic import in Next.js.
Something like this:

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const GeneratePdf = dynamic(() => import("./GeneratePDF"), { ssr: false });
```

Where `GeneratePDF` is a component. Internal structure of `GeneratePDF` is someting like this.

```js
import { jsPDF} from "jspdf";

function GeneratePDF (){
    const handlePDF = async () => {
        const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4", false);
        // do whatever you want in your pdf and finally save your pdf
        await doc.save("mypdf.pdf");
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={handlePDF}>Generate PDF</button>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), I found [this tutorial with Next.js](https://dev.to/wonder2210/generating-pdf-files-using-next-js-24dm).

`pages/index.tsx`:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const GeneratePDF = dynamic(()=>import("./../src/components/GeneratePDF"),{ssr:false});
const app =()=>{
        const ref = React.useRef();

        return(<div className="main">
        <div className="content" ref={ref}>
        <h1>Hello PDF</h1>
        <img id="image" src="/images/image_header.jpg" width="300" height="200"/>
        <p id="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam animi, molestiae quaerat assumenda neque culpa ab aliquam facilis eos nesciunt! Voluptatibus eligendi vero amet dolorem omnis provident beatae nihil earum!
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, est. Magni animi fugit voluptates mollitia officia libero in. Voluptatibus nisi assumenda accusamus deserunt sunt quidem in, ab perspiciatis ad rem.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil accusantium reprehenderit, quasi dolorum deserunt, nisi dolores quae officiis odio vel natus! Pariatur enim culpa velit consequatur sapiente natus dicta alias!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur, asperiores error laudantium corporis sunt earum incidunt expedita quo quidem delectus fugiat facilis quia impedit sit magni quibusdam ipsam reiciendis quaerat!
        </p>
        </div>
        <GeneratePDF html={ref}/>
        </div>);
}

export default app;
```